# How to have a single tool tip display for multiple controls

Tags: tooltip, mouseover

I have a number of different controls that I want to display the same tool tip. The issue is that the 'for' property appears to be single value. Is there a way to have a single tool tip respond to the mouse over on multiple controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a single tool tip for all controls using the following steps

1. Create a div element
2. Set style.display = 'none' for the div
3. Append it to the body of the document
4. In mouseover event , get the mouse co-ordinates using evt.clientX and evt.clientY and then set 
      style.display = 'block'
      style.position = 'absolute'
      style.top = evt.clientY +'px'
      style.left = evt.clientX + 'px' for the div